# Múltiplos projetos utilizando um único arquivo "properties"

Tags: java-ee

Tenho um produto que está distribuído em vários projetos WEB MAVEN independentes que acessam uma única base MYSQL. Decidi dividí-lo em vários projetos para que cada módulo fique em um servidor diferente, dividindo a carga. E também porque são módulos com propósitos diferentes e não fazia sentido entregar tudo em um único pacote.

Ocorre que esses módulos têm algumas funcionalidades em comum e eu criei uma biblioteca com as classes comuns, de maneira que todos os projetos utilizam essa biblioteca.

Da mesma maneira, cada módulo possui seu próprio arquivo *.properties. Eu gostaria de unificar esses arquivos em um único arquivo *.properties, de modo que todos os módulos pudessem acessá-lo, facilitando alterações em tempo de execução. Pensei em colocá-lo nessa biblioteca, mas continuaria com o mesmo problema, pois cada projeto tem o seu próprio JAR dessa biblioteca, além do mais, seria necessário extrair o JAR, alterar o *.properties e compactá-lo novamente, o que inviabiliza o procedimento.

Existe também a possibilidade de colocar todas essas chaves numa tabela na base de dados, já que todos os módulos a acessam.

Existe alguma solução mais elegante para essa situação?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solução básica é colocar a configuração em bancos de dados e carregar os dados na inicialização de cada aplicação.

Outra possibilidade é definir um diretório de rede e ler o arquivo properties dele. Todas as máquinas (servidores) teriam que enxergar esse diretório, que pode ser mapeado para facilitar mudanças.

Uma terceira opção é disponibilizar as configurações via webservice e um servidor "central" que cada aplicação consulta durante a inicialização.

Para atualizar as configurações em "tempo de execução", poderia haver um timer para recarregá-las em intervalos de tempo ou mesmo uma funcionalidade específica para isso (um botão "recarregar" em algum lugar).  Isso depende muitos dos requisitos de alteração, isto é, se pode haver interação do usuário e a frequência de mudanças.

Quanto ao jar dessa biblioteca, infelizmente não há mágica. O Jar deve ser distribuído em cada aplicação, com ou sem o properties. Se houverem várias aplicações num mesmo servidor, um único jar pode ser importado no `classpath` através de uma configuração no seu servidor de aplicação. Isso evitaria a duplicação do jar numa mesma máquina.

Se esse jar for frequentemente atualizado, a sua atualização poderia ser automatizada via scripts que verificam um local na rede e atualizam diretamente as libs dos sistemas publicados. Entretanto, provavelmente será necessário incluir nesse script a reinicialização das aplicações. Em geral creio ser um exagero. Nenhum módulo de configuração deve mudar tanto assim.

Enfim, foram algumas ideias baseadas em requisitos abstratos. Se houver algum detalhe ou requisito mais específico sobre o seu problema, edite sua pergunta para refletir isso.